# Why can't I migrate my postgres database in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql

I switched my database from sqlite to postgres for deployment on heroku. When I did that and attempted to run heroku run rake db:migrate -a  I saw this error: 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "pay_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date HINT: You might need to specify "USING pay_date::date". : ALTER TABLE "recurring_payments" ALTER COLUMN "pay_date" TYPE date
 So i created a migration to fix this, but when I run rake db:migrate to run the migration, I see this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

However, when I check my services, I see that it is running, and it is configured to listen on port 5432. What else could be causing this issue?

Also, if I add this line to database.yml:

```
  host: localhost
```

The error changes to this:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "localhost" to address: Name or service not known
```

Perhaps this is more promising?

Comment: Define "migrate". What are you doing?

Comment: It strikes me as unlikely that you have a Windows installation of PostgreSQL listening on a unix socket with a unix path. You have tried connecting to localhost, have you?

Comment: "Migrating in Windows" doesn't really describe well what you're doing. Do you mean migrating from one Windows machine to another? From Linux to Windows? Windows to Linux? Something else? What command are you typing in where?

Comment: I switched the database from sqlite to postgres for deployment on heroku. When I did that and attempted to run heroku run rake db:migrate -a <appname> I saw this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "pay_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING pay_date::date".
: ALTER TABLE "recurring_payments" ALTER COLUMN "pay_date" TYPE date. So i created a migration to fix this, but when I run rake db:migrate to run the migration, I see the error mentioned in the question

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but edit your question to improve it. Are you sure to be doing that on a Windows system? Most servers are running Linux and the error message in your question smells like Linux one

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple problems:

By default Rails uses Unix sockets to connect to PostgreSQL. Hence the original error message.

Adding the `host` key switches Rails to a TCP/IP connection instead, which is what you want in Windows.

Now you seem to have another problem: `localhost` cannot be resolved to an IP address, which suggests that you have general configuration problems on your Windows machines which are unrelated to Rails or PostgreSQL.

Check if your `hosts` file is messed up or if your (personal) firewall is blocking Rails or PostgreSQL. Try running `ping localhost`.

If all else fails try using `host: 127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: When I run ping localhost, I get 4 successful transmissions, which I think is what should happen. However, I still get the same error with that as the host name. If I change the host name to 127.0.0.1, I get this error: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: If I run netstat -ano, I can see that there is a process listening on port 5432

Comment: try `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`  it's ip6 for localhost. a don all the tests that confirm that your postgresql server is running.